# Select All records or top dynamic number of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like

```
DECLARE @TOP VARCHAR(10) = '10'
```

I need to select top @top values from a table like

I had used

```
select top (convert(int,@top)) * from <table>
```

but my problem is the `@top` value may have the value 'ALL' also. That time this query is not possible. Please suggest a query to return result whatever the value for `@top` (either 'all' or value)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid extra complication, run one of two queries:

```
IF @Top = 'All'
BEGIN
     SELECT *
       FROM <table>
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT TOP CAST(@Top AS INT) *
       FROM <table>
END
```

It's a small overhead in typing text that make the code easier to read in the future.

Dynamic queries are useful if there is no other way, but explicit queries are better for future understanding and in performance terms (can't determine execution plan until query is constructed).

A slightly better way would be to use an INT variable, were 0 indicates ALL, and there's no requirement to CAST/CONVERT the variable.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was down-voted, but I can't tell who did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @TOP NVARCHAR(10)= N'10'

declare @sql as nvarchar(max) = N'select '
if @top <> N'ALL'
    set @sql = @sql + N'top ' + @top
set @sql = @sql + N' * from table1'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution can help ypu:

```
declare @top varchar(10) 
set @top = 'all'

select top(case @top when 'all' then 1000000 else cast(@top as int) end)
    *
from MyTable
```

Value 1000000 is random value, you can set maximum integer value to sure to get all rows.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @TOP NVARCHAR(100) = 'ALL'
IF @TOP = 'ALL' SET @TOP = '100 PERCENT '
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP '+@TOP+' * FROM table_name' 
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: I thought about doing it this way. 100 PERCENT is better than the max bigint, but at the point you are doing dynamic SQL I think you're better off not using TOP when it is 'all'. The only time I cn think of that 100 PERCENT should be used is if the @top were actually being a % instead of a row count.

Comment: @KarlKieninger, I agree with you, since dynamic query is used TOP 100 PERCENT can be avoided, but then else statement should also be added... that I think make query look more complicated... this is much simpler to read and understand...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Veljasije's answer, but avoid using an arbitrary number for all. If you know your data you should be fine picking a large number as he suggests.

```
DECLARE @top VARCHAR(10) = 'all'
SELECT TOP (CASE @top 
                 WHEN 'all' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders) 
                 ELSE CAST(@top AS BIGINT) 
            END) 
       * 
  FROM Orders
```

However, I like the idea of using max INT, but TOP takes a BIGINT so you want that. I tried:

```
DECLARE @top VARCHAR(10) = 'all'
SELECT TOP (CASE @top 
                 WHEN 'all' THEN 9223372036854775807 
                 ELSE CAST(@top AS BIGINT) 
            END) 
       * 
  FROM Orders
```

And that unexpectedly errors:

> Msg 1060, Level 15, State 1, Line 34 The number of rows provided for a
>   TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer

However this work:

```
SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) * FROM Orders
```

So I'm confused. If anyone can provide insight here, great, otherwise I may open a question on that.